# Local Notification: Detect dismissing on foreground

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am trying to detect when user dismissed a local notification on foreground case. I am playing music because I needed to add a sound to my notification at silent mode. For notification I couldn't find any way to play sound for notification, so I play music instead of that. It works well on background mode and when user tapped but I couldn't detect swipe up -dismiss- the notification to stop.